# What's the main difference between graph.addCell and graph.insertVertex?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

What is the main difference between graph.addCell and graph.insertVertex? Can they be used interchangeably? When do I use each one?

The docs for both functions can be found [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
mxGraph.prototype.insertVertex = function(parent, id, value,
    x, y, width, height, style, relative)
{
    var vertex = this.createVertex(parent, id, value, x, y, width, height, style, relative);

    return this.addCell(vertex, parent);
};
```

https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/src/js/view/mxGraph.js#L4471

A cell is either a vertex or edge, see [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

addCell adds the given cell. insertVertex/Edge is a wrapper that creates the vertex/edge and calls addCell.